# Moving a div from bottom to top, using only css

Tags: html, css

I have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/my5La/

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
<div id="third"></div>
<div id="fourth"></div>
```

Now, I would like to move the green (third) rectangle between first and second div. And I need it to get in between those two, just like it was in there in the first place (so the second rectangle would move downward, and the green one would go up).

Now, is it possible of doing so when first rectangle's height is varying? If not, is it possible at all?

I need it because google adsense is saying, that the first ad in html is paying the most, so I need to get my main ad to the bottom of the page since it is not getting as many clicks as other ad's on my site (and then move it back up, preferably with css only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reorder elements using `order` property of flexbox layout:

```css
/* flexbox on body or any other wrapper */
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#first,
#third {
    order: -1;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/my5La/2/

But as well as others, I advice you to obey Google AdSense ToS.

Comment: But they (Google) basically tell me to do that - on they help pages they tell that the first ad in code is the most profitable one, so they tell to move non-main ads on the bottom of the page...

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with CSS is difficult to impossible without fixed height divs.

You can use jQuery's `insertBefore` or `insertAfter`:

```
$("#third").insertBefore($("#second"));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/screenmutt/9g82Z/1/)

**EDIT**

Reordering ads is a violation of [Google's AdSense Policy](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736)

Comment: Could you quote the exact paragraph that prohibits reordering? Because I've found none by that link.

Comment: "Our program policies do not permit any alteration to AdSense code which artificially inflates ad performance or harms advertiser conversions."

Answer (score -2):

since they're all the same shape and size, you could just change there color giving the illusion that a div's position has changed. Seems a lot easier to do that than moving actual HTML elements around.