# Moving a DIV using only CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to move a DIV element to the bottom of the body but I can't modify the HTML structure. I thought some existing thread could help me as they explain exactly what I'm looking for but it doesn't seem to be working in my case : [Moving a div from bottom to top, using only css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336880/moving-a-div-from-bottom-to-top-using-only-css). I might be missing something.

Here's my page : https://www.tr-architecte.fr/page-220-auriples-drome

```
<section>
  <article class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <div class="txt">...</div>
    <div class="gallery">...</div>
  </article>
</section>
```

The concerned element is DIV.txt. I want it to be placed right after the div.gallery but can't do it manually as the photos gallery generates itself automatically at the bottom. I can modify classes and styles though.

Let me know if you need more infos.

Comment: My mistake. I edited the question with code sample. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.container-fluid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container-fluid * {
  order: 1;
}

.txt {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">1. Row</div>
    <div class="txt">2. Text</div>
    <div class="gallery">3. Gallery</div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: That works just fine ! Thank you, that'll be usefull !

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the html structure it's rought, I would have a solution.

Not the best, I don't recommend it, but here it goes:

```
position: absolute;
```

This goes on the div with the class .row that contains your text. After the position absolute you have to use `bottom: - something px` and `left: something px`. Then you go to your div with the id: social and generate some `padding-top: something px`.

What I used to test it was :

This on .row

```
position: absolute;
left: 450px;
bottom: -535px;
```

This on #social

```
padding-top: 200px;
```

As I said, it's a bad practice and I don't recommend it, but since you don't have access to the html, it's your choice.

Comment: display:flex seems more appropriate and less "rough". I think I used it once but can't recall where and how.